# Finding number of types of accounts from each customer

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am having a lot of trouble with trying to construct a query that will give me the name of each customer and the number of different types of accounts each has. The three types are Checkings, Savings, and CD.

```
customers:
+--------+--------+
| cid    | name   |
+--------+--------+
| 1      | a      | 
| 2      | b      |
| 3      | c      |
+--------+--------+

accounts:
+-----------+-----------+
| aid       | type      |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | Checkings |
| 2         | Savings   |
| 3         | Checkings |
| 4         | CD        |
| 5         | CD        |
| 6         | Checkings |
+-----------+-----------+

transactions:
+--------+--------+--------+
| tid    | cid    | aid    |
+--------+--------+--------+
| 1      | 1      | 1      |
| 2      | 1      | 2      |
| 3      | 2      | 3      |
| 4      | 3      | 4      |
| 5      | 1      | 5      |
| 6      | 3      | 4      |
| 7      | 1      | 6      |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

The expected answer would be:

a, 3

b, 1

c, 1

Getting the names is simple enough, but how can I keep count of each individual's account as well as compare the accounts to make sure that it is not the same type?

Answer (score 1):

just add `DISTINCT` inside the `COUNT`

```
SELECT  a.cid, a.name, COUNT(DISTINCT c.type) totalCount
FROM    customers a
        INNER JOIN transactions b
            ON a.cis = b.cid
        INNER JOIN accounts c
            ON b,aid = c.aid
GROUP BY a.cid, a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFiddleExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd269/28)**

```
SELECT 
a."name", 
COUNT(DISTINCT c."type") totalCount
FROM    customers a
        INNER JOIN transactions b
            ON a."cid" = b."cid"
        INNER JOIN accounts c
            ON b."aid" = c."aid"
GROUP BY a."cid", a."name"
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
```

Result:

```
| NAME | TOTALCOUNT |
---------------------
|    a |          3 |
|    b |          1 |
|    c |          1 |
```